# Moments of discrete and continuous random variables

Tags: probability

Let X be a random variable. Can someone give me an example when $E[X]< \infty, E[X^2]=\infty$ for a discrete and continuous random variables?

Comment: For each $n=1,2,\dotsc,$ define the RV $X:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ by $\mathbb{P}(X=(\sqrt{2})^n)=2^{-n}$. Then $\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-1}\approx 2.4142$ while $\mathbb{E}(X^2)=\infty$, which I leave to you to verify on your own. I cannot think of a continuous example at the moment, but maybe someone else will come along with one, otherwise I'd post this as an answer.

Comment: Actually I just realized my example won't work if you're looking for purely integer-valued RVs, sorry. I'll leave it up anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You may know

- $\int\limits_1^\infty \frac1{x^3} dx=\frac12$
- $\int\limits_1^\infty \frac1{x^2} dx=1$
- $\int\limits_1^\infty \frac1{x} dx=\infty$

so this can be simply manipulated to give a density for a continuous random variable $X$ taking values greater than or equal to $1$, with finite mean and infinite second moment and so infinite variance

Then get a discrete random variable $Y$ on the integers where $\mathbb P(Y=n) = \mathbb P(n \le X \lt n+1)$

Comment: Curiously, it seems $\sum\limits_1^\infty \dfrac{2n+1}{n(n+1)^2} = \sum\limits_1^\infty \dfrac{1}{n^2}$